# minimum power required algorithm

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, greedy

You are given a logic circuit that can be modeled as a rooted tree-the leaves are the primary inputs, the internal nodes are the gates, and the root is the single output of the circuit. Each gate can be powered by a high or low supply voltage. A gate powered by a lower supply voltage consumes less power but has a
weaker output signal. You want to minimize power while ensuring that the circuit is reliable. To ensure reliability, you should not have a gate powered by a low supply voltage drive another gate powered by a low
supply voltage. All gates consume 1 nanowatt when connected to the low supply voltage and 2 nanowatts when connected to the high supply voltage.

Design an efficient algorithm that takes as input a logic circuit and selects supply voltages for each gate to minimize power consumption while ensuring reliable operation.

In this question what I think is that, it can solve solve by using greedy or Dynamic. But I am confused from where I can start this problem to think.
Please help.

Comment: No karoly, actually I am preparing for a interview in Google, that's why I asked the same question.

Comment: Karoly, I think should be a tag that is "No-homework".

Answer (score 1):

From the requirement "you should not have a gate powered by a low supply voltage drive another gate powered by a low supply voltage", we get that our task is to find a maximal independent set in the tree (minus the leaves maybe, I don't know if they are considered to be powered or not).

While the problem is NP-hard for general graphs, it can be solved quickly and efficiently for trees. You can read this [simple 3-page article](http://ccrcweb.cs.nthu.edu.tw/~sheujp/public/journal/3.pdf) for the details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a maximum independent set of the tree, while the points belong to the independent set have low supply voltage. Besides dynamic programming, there is a very simple linear greedy algorithm:

1. Choosing all the leaves (the gates which are not drove by other gates) as low voltage.
2. Delete all the leaves and their direct fathers.
3. Now some internal nodes become the new leaves. Repeat to 1 until all the nodes are processed.